# sql query with comparison but without removing without subquerying

Tags: sql

my question is, is it possible to select certain rows in a table according to a comparison rule without removing anything from the result. To clarify what i want to to imagine following example.

i have a table with two values,

```
 A | B | C
 1   0   hey
 1   1   there
 2   1   this
 3   0   is
 3   1   a
 4   0   test
```

now i want to select the rows that have a 0 in the B column, and an a in the C column without removing the results that don't have a 0 in column B but the same value in column A.
For that i could do a

```
 select C from T where A in (select A from T where B = 0);
```

but isn't it possible to select all C values where column B contains a 0 and that match column A with those?

I'd gladly stand by if more information is needed since it is a quite fuzzy question, but SQL can be confusing sometimes.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the results you are looking for?

Comment: Am I right that you mean column A not row A?

Comment: @gordon, the result would be "hey, there, is, a, test" the only thing that should miss is "this" since it has no 0 in column B whatsoever, the other entries all have a 0 in column B and are linked by A

Comment: @jester yes, column A and B, sry, correted the wrong ones

Answer (score 0):

Tough to tell without your example result set; but maybe something like this:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM myTable
WHERE (B = 0 AND C LIKE '%A%')
OR (B <> 0 AND B = A)
```

Comment: I have voted to delete my answer as it is almost the same as yours, but yours is actually correct.

Comment: Haha; still a complete stab in the dark.  Pay no attention to the type mismatch between what is assumed to be an INT column (A) and a BIT column (B).

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want an `or` condition:

```
select C
from MyTable
where b = 0 or A in (select A from T where B = 0)
```

Is this the version you want:

```
select C
from MyTable
where C = 'a' or A in (select A from T where B = 0)
```

Comment: wouldn't this be simply selecting all B rows with 0 two times, since I get all A values where B is 0 and then select all rows that match any of the A values. Though it might be possible to do it with an OR statement.... i just have to think about it a bit

Comment: @Xtroce . . . The `where` clause is only processed once for each row.  It is either true or false, even if both clauses are true.  You are thinking of a `union all` operation.  You might want a `distinct`, if there are duplicate C values across the rows.

Comment: thnks but i mean that the b = 0 in your example is already covered through the A in ( select A from T where B = 0 )

Comment: I solved the problem already this way, my question goes more in the direction that i want to solve this selection task without a subquery since in the real life version i use this goes along with several joins and then the query gets quite big and i think it is possible to select everything that i want without joining everything twice.